# Can a VPS provider see the IP address I use when connecting?

Tags: vpn, webserver, ip, vps

I recently purchased a VPS. Can the provider see the IP address I use when connecting to my VPS?

Comment: You tagged this VPN. Do you mean to suggest that you are using one? Or what is the tag for?

Comment: This is a very simple question and shows no research at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can see your public IP which is making the connection to VPS through their network.

Comment: Would using a VPN when connecting simply solve this issue?